# Android - Context in ListFragment does'nt work when called from AsyncTask in other Activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, android-context

I want to refresh the `List` of a `ListFragment`. Therefore I created a method in my `ListFragment`:

```
public void setAdapter(List<String> valueList) {
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valueList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And in my `Activity` I have a `AsyncTask` where I call the method above in `onPostExecute`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> valueList) {
        OtherClass otherClasst = new OtherClass();

        otherclass.setAdapter(valueList);
    }
```

Everything should work fine. The `valueList` isn't empty or something like that and also the `onPostExecute` gets called.

So now my Problem is, that if I initialize the `Context ctx` in the `onCreate` method of my `ListFragment` I get a `NullPointerException`. When I initialize it in my `setAdapter` method with `ctx = getActivity` I get the same error. The only thing I can do is to get the `context` of the class with the `AsyncTask`, but then nothing is shown in the app.

So how do I get this to work?

Comment: set the adapter in onViewCreated method of fragment

Comment: What is `OtherClass`, and why are you creating a new one?

Comment: You have to update the current instance of the ListFragment. If your list fragment is called OtherClass then you'll have to get the current instance first and update that with the above mentioned setAdapter method.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling `setAdapter` from `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask`, then your `activity` might have destroyed and may be that's why you are getting `null` context by calling `getActivity`.

Initialize the `adapter`(make it global) outside `setAdapter`, may be in `onCreateView` method of `Fragment` like this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valueList);
```

And `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask` just update the `valueList` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: This doesn't work. Beacause for some reason calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() throws a null pointer exception as well. Is it worth mentioning that the ListFragment is inside the Activity that calls the Method setAdapter?